# What is an easy way to input an emoji character into Intellij IDEA running on Windows?

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm running IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1 on Windows 7.

In the [release notes](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/specials/idea/whatsnew.html) there is mention of emoji support on Windows/Linux (albeit in monochrome).

I can't figure out an easy way of decorating my code with fun characters!